# Why does my request return an ERR_BAD_REQUEST?

Tags: javascript, axios

I am making a request from postman that returns the requested information without problem, additionally I did the test using curl and in the same way it returns the information successfully.But when doing it from axios it returns an ERR_BAD_REQUEST, the code is the following:

```
const axios = require('axios');
let payload = {
  "payment_method": {
    "type": "CARD",
    "installments": 2,
    "token": "tok_prod_some_token"
  }
};

let config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://hereismyurl/v1/tokens/cards',
 data:payload,
 headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
     'Authorization': 'Bearer pub_prod_some_public_key'

  },

};

axios(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I can't understand what I'm sending wrong in my request

Comment: Postman has option to generate valid javascript code with request. Try to test it's output and compare with yours.

Comment: This is the code I am using